# Class not found exception, when querying from doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am getting this really weird exception when I try to query from Doctrine:

> > Class string does not exist
> >
> > 500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException

I have no idea what the problem could be. Have you seen anything similar?

I don't even know which details are relevant. I put it all here:

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709856/) is the full stack trace  (/mnt/data/Projects/F5 is where the project is located).

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709874/) is the definition of fields in class `User` and [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709880/) for class `Email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well , this surely jumps the eye

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception ReflectionException: "Class string does not exist" at /mnt/data/Projects/F5/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php line 233
```

also , https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5732 had a similar error mensage and some insight on the error

Comment: yeah, it was exactly the same problem. But I don't get it, that code was generated by Symfony!